Is it possible to reflect a line over another line in three-dimensional space if both lines are skew lines?
If it is possible, what are the steps that should be taken to get the reflected line? I assume it starts with finding out the points on both lines such that the distance between them is the shortest. Thank you for any help.

You can reflect a point over a line by reflecting it over the line in the plane spanned by the point and the line (this is the same as finding the nearest point on the line to the point and then reflecting over that point), reflecting a line can be done by reflecting every point

Also: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.
